# Large File transfer error in Socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp

I m building a code for transferring a file from a server.c to client.c program . But during run time It is not working properly . I m sending the file in chunks of 512 bytes . The source file i 784 KB has nearly 88000 names in it.

This program works correctly on 127.0.0.1 but it is not working properly when i connect two computers on lan/WIFI .

I m not including the complete file only the function with which i m going to transfer/recieve the file

Help me to find the error in the code.

If u test it then do between two computers .

If u guys have a better code for file sending and recieving please post it ,see to it that i need the control out of the function after transfer is done . I really appreciate your help .

I M USING LINUX FOR THE FOLLOWING PURPOSE & GCC FOR COMPILTION

Server.c
ONLY THE FUNCTION

```
void filesender(char fs_name[],int ncfd)
{
char sdbuf[LENGTH];
FILE *fs=fopen(fs_name,"r");
if(fs==NULL)
{
    perror("\n[Server] File is not found on Server Directory");
    exit(1);
}

bzero(sdbuf, LENGTH); 
int fs_block_sz; 

while((fs_block_sz = fread(sdbuf, sizeof(char), LENGTH, fs))>0)
{
    if(send(ncfd, sdbuf, fs_block_sz, 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("\n[Server] Error: Sending File Failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    bzero(sdbuf, LENGTH);
}
puts("\n[Server] File Sended Successfull");
}
```

Client.c

```
void filereciever(int id,int ncfd)
{
char revbuf[LENGTH]; //Buffer variable to hold recieved data
char *fr_name;
char fid=id;
asprintf(&fr_name,"result%c.txt",fid);

FILE *fr = fopen(fr_name, "a");
if(fr == NULL)
{
    printf("[Server] File %s Cannot be opened.\n", fr_name);
}
else
{
    bzero(revbuf, LENGTH); 
    int fr_block_sz = 0;
    while((fr_block_sz = recv(ncfd, revbuf, LENGTH, 0)) > 0)
    {
        int write_sz = fwrite(revbuf, sizeof(char), fr_block_sz, fr);
        if(write_sz < fr_block_sz)
        {
            puts("\n[Server] File write failed");
        }
        bzero(revbuf, LENGTH);
        if (fr_block_sz == 0 || fr_block_sz != 512) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(fr_block_sz < 0)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN)
        {
            puts("\n[Server] Error: recv() timed out");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n[Server] Error: recv() failed due to errno = %d", errno);
        }
    }
    printf("[Server] File successfully received from server!\n");
    fclose(fr);
}}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error? What's the value of `errno`?

Comment: I suppose, as @Calvin says, that on a real network socket only part of the buffer may get transmitted (but not when transmitting to the localhost). The man page for send() also mentions that " If the message is too long to pass through the underlying protocol, send() shall fail and no data shall be transmitted." I suppose the underlying protocol changes if you use a real network.

Comment: I guess he found some data is missed in the transmission, due to the reason of incomplete send() I said on answer below.

Comment: @PeterSchneider incomplete `send()` is also classified as success. The man page say: Upon successful completion, the number of bytes which were sent is returned.

Comment: Generally I'd recommend to read the seminal network books by Richard Stevens if you are doing any serious network programming. There are many subtleties which need to be addressed for robust code.

Comment: @Calvin yes; the cases I mentioned are distinct (too long is a failure according to the man page, but that may only happen for true "messages", perhaps only applicable when using flags). I was a bit puzzled by the use of send(). According to the man page it amounts to write() when no flags are used, so probably the "too long" error won't occur with 0 flags as in the post.

Comment: there is no errno value present . The data is transmitted but on the recieving side it is instead of collecting in one file it get collected in multiple files . On server side i m writing filesender(); 3 times and at same time  i m recieving 3 files on client side . the thing is server shows i sended 3 files on the client side it shows it recieved 3 file but when i open the files on client side data of 1st file sended by server is filled in all the 3 files recieved at client side

Comment: @stealthshadow I can't make head or tail of that. Please try again. You send 3 files and you receive 3 files so what exactly is the problem? NB you don't need any of those `bzero()` calls.

Comment: i m just using bzero to make buffer zero so that when i make a write it doesn't write the garbage characters when less data is recieved

Comment: server side :- I m sending three files one by one calling the function 3 times . 
Client side :- Receiving the data in three different files and saving it.
When i run the code server shows file send successful three times .
On client side it shows file receive successful three times. But when i open all the 3 files on client side they all have the data of 1st file which was send from the server . and there is no data on client side of 2nd and 3rd file sent by server

Comment: My point is that if you code your `send()` and `fwrite()` calls correctly, using the read-count values returned by `fread()` and `recv()` respectively, as you appear to have done, there is no necessity for zeroing buffers at all. The 'garbage' is beyond the read-count, and you aren't doing anything with the buffer beyond the read-count, so zeroing it accomplishes precisely nothing.

Comment: `if (fr_block_sz == 0 || fr_block_sz != 512) { break; }` The beauty of it!

Answer (score 1):

You should check the result of `send()`

For TCP socket, `send()` put the data into OS's internal queue, which may sometime fill part of your requested size. You are supposed to handle such incomplete send and retry later.

---

EDIT: As the OP disclosed more information in the comments, it seems the problem is not (yet) related to network, it seems that there is bug choosing file to send, and he need to post the relevant code for further diagnose.

Comment: So what should i use in place of send() logically it seems correct

Comment: @Calvin Posix requires that `send()` in blocking mode transfers the entire buffer.

Comment: @EJP this is not true, for blocking socket `send()` may still decide to eat partial requested buffer, even one byte. `send()` blocks only if the sending buffer is totally full. It sounds either you or the Linux community wrongly interpret the POSIX requirement.

Comment: @Calvin Me and the Linux and Windows and Solaris implementors and all the TCP/IP implementors on the news:comp.protocols.tcp-ip newsgroup. The Linux *man* page states "When the message does not fit into the send buffer of the socket, send() normally blocks, unless the socket has been placed in nonblocking I/O mode". So do the Windows MSDN page and the Solaris *man* page. The other problem with your answer is that it doesn't account for the reported symptoms.

Comment: @EJP I did a quick test and verified you were correct. I was not aware that non-blocking plays the critical difference here. I have almost never used blocking mode, but then any serious server code should use non-blocking mode with M:N threading model to prevent unexpected blocking. And I agree that the current problem for OP is not related to network, it seems there is bug choosing file to send, which he need to post the related code for further diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

> server side :- I'm sending three files one by one calling the function 3 times.
>
> Client side :- Receiving the data in three different files and saving it. When i run the code server shows file send successful three times . On client side it shows file receive successful three times. But when i open all the 3 files on client side they all have the data of 1st file which was send from the server.

If this is an accurate statement of your problem, which isn't clear, it can only mean that you sent the same file three times, instead of sending three different files. You would need to post the code that calls these functions for further comment to be possible.

Comment: I m sending three different files on server side and on client side i m receiving in 3 diff files . The thing is on client side data present on all three received file is of the first file i have sended .
I know it sounds weird But during run time this thing happens.
This Prog works completely fine on 127.0.0.1 .
I would post the full code after some time

Comment: I suggest you check the contents of the files if you're certain you're sending three different ones. There can't be any doubt that you're receiving what you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

I overheard that is what happens when zero becomes a number, a professor had said.
As you can see in the `while()` part where you receive the data you are checking it against zero yet the `recv()` function will always collect something only that it will collect null. You could solve your challenges If you could possibly check to see if the `recv()` has received the last batch of file items then close the `while()` loop but if that would be tedious I would recommend a fast approach by closing the socket once the `send()` sends the whole file so that the `recv()` function will have nothing to receive and end the `while()` loop then reconnect to the socket.